# Div did not show up in d3 v4

Tags: html, d3.js

I tried to add a div at top of my other rects by appending a "div"

```
   <div id="canvas"/>
       <script>
        var svg = d3.select(document.getElementById('canvas')).append("svg")
    svg.append("rect").attr("x",10).attr("y", 10).attr("width", 100).attr("height", 100)
              .style("fill", "red")
              .style("stroke", "#000")
        svg.append('div')
                    .style('position','absolute')
                    .style('top', "10px")
                    .style('left', "10px")
                    .style('z-index', 9999)
                    .style('width', "120px")
                    .style('height', "50px")
                    .style('background-color', "#ff0")
     </script>
```

see the running code here:

```
https://jsfiddle.net/coolshare/xoqe9gou/7/
```

But the div never show up...

Any suggestion?

thanks

coolshare

Comment: It will **never** show up: you cannot append a div (or any other HTML element) to an SVG.

Comment: http://bl.ocks.org/jfreels/6735318

Comment: How is this bl.ocks related to your question? It's appending divs to the **body**, not to an SVG: `d3.select('body').selectAll('div').data(data).enter().append('div')`.

Comment: I see. May be I can try foreignObject...thanks

Comment: this does not work ?  .append('div').append("svg")